# What are the 5 blaphemies against the Immaculate Heart of Mary?

Tags: virgin-mary, immaculate-conception, blasphemy, fatima, immaculate-heart

What are the 5 blasphemies against the Immaculate Heart of Mary that Our Lady of Fatima mentioned? Which sects utter these blasphemies?

Answer (score 3):

The 5 blasphemies against the Immaculate Heart of Mary (given by Our Lady of Fatima to Sister Lucy, May 29 or 30, 1930):

> 1. Blasphemies against the [Immaculate Conception](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52893/1787).
> 2. Blasphemies against [Her [perpetual] Virginity](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP028.html).
> 3. Blasphemies against Her Divine Maternity, in refusing at the same time to recognize Her as the Mother of men.
> 4. The blasphemies of those who publicly seek to sow in the hearts of children indifference or scorn, or even hatred of this Immaculate
>    Mother.
> 5. The offences of those who outrage Her directly in Her holy images.

<sup>quoted in frère Michel de la Sainte Trinité, [*The Whole Truth about Fatima (vol. 2): The Secret and the Church (1917-1942)*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6231)</sup>

The schismatic Eastern "Orthodox" and Protestants frequently utter these blasphemies:

> Father Alonso asks: who are those who might commit this offence against the Immaculate Heart of Mary? The answer leaves no doubt:*
>
> > In the first place and in general the protestant sects who refuse to receive the dogma defined by Pius IX [in [*Ineffabilis Deus*]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52893/1787) and who have continued to maintain that the Blessed Virgin was conceived with the stain of original sin and even personal sins. The same can be said of the (dissident) Eastern Christians, since, in spite of their great Marian devotion, they too refuse this dogma.

<sup>**La Gran Promesa del Corazon de Maria en Pontevedra* (3<sup>rd</sup> ed.), Centro Mariano, Madrid, 1977, pp. 56-57</sup>

> Although the Orthodox admit it, the majority of protestants also reject the perfect and [perpetual virginity of Mary](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP028.html) «before, during and after giving birth».

<sup>frère Michel de la Sainte Trinité, [*The Whole Truth about Fatima (vol. 2): The Secret and the Church (1917-1942)*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6231)</sup>

Protestants (unlike the schismatic "Orthodox") are often [iconoclast](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34049), who utter blasphemy #5, too.

Comment: I was thinking about the same recently. Like who blasphemes against virgin Mary? And then I realized what you wrote above. So the whole world suffers mostly because of protestants. This is why we have 5 first Saturdays devotion which can bring peace and the conversion.